# Why EOF is recognized if it is first character in line?

Tags: c, unix

I wrote this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int numspaces, numtabs, numnl, c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (c == ' ') ++numspaces;
    if (c == '\t') ++numtabs;
    if (c == '\n') ++ numnl;
  }
  printf("Spaces:\t\t%d\nTabs:\t\t%d\nNew lines:\t\t%d\n", numspaces, numtabs, numnl);
}
```

I think this while loop must finish when I press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and "return". It does if <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> is the first thing I type in a line. But if I start a line with other character (letter, space, tab) and then <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and then "return" - the loop continues.

I test this in Mac OS X terminal, I see it echoing `^D` and it still continues the loop. What am I missing here?

Comment: unrelated: initialize all those values that are currently indeterminate even if you make it through the loop at least once for every distinct character type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> or more precisely the character set to the `VEOF` entry of the `c_cc` field of a termios control structure (`stty` is the easiest way to query and modify those settings from the command line) is to be interpreted as (quote from the Single Unix Specification V4):

> Special character on input, which is recognized if the ICANON flag is set. When received, all the bytes waiting to be read are immediately passed to the process without waiting for a , and the EOF is discarded. Thus, if there are no bytes waiting (that is, the EOF occurred at the beginning of a line), a byte count of zero shall be returned from the read(), representing an end-of-file indication. If ICANON is set, the EOF character shall be discarded when processed.

Thus to send a EOF indication from a terminal you hit <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> once when there is no bytes waiting to be returned (typically at the start of a line), and twice when there are some.

Answer (score 3):

If you type something, hit the return key, and then hit <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, it will stop.

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> will end input to the program, but only if there is nothing left in the terminal's buffer.

FYI, `EOF` is not really a character. `getchar()` just returns an integer value `EOF` (typically -1) when there is nothing left to read.

Also, note that this question only applies to terminals. If you piped it in from a file, things would be behave just as you expect.

Comment: I read your answer a few times and I'm almost sure that you didn't answer OP question **why** it has to be first character in the input buffer? And **how** is reading EOF from end of line different from reading from beginning of the line?

Comment: @zubergu, I answered why it had be the beginning of the line: the terminal won't end input until then. (Terminals do all sorts of special things...Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-D.) Now, why the terminal chooses not to end input to the program if the buffer is non-empty is a decision made by its authors.

Comment: *"EOF is not really a character"* uhm what's `\x04`?

Comment: @Mehrdad, good question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character. It can be used with significance relating to end-of-input or end-of-file. But the OP's program is *not* being passed that character. Also, think about a binary file (e.g. an image). If it happens to have some byte of value 4, that doesn't mean that is the last bytes of the file. There is no byte that signifies the end of that file; there just are no more bytes after the last one.

Comment: @PaulDraper: Right... but are you sure the OP's code is not being passed that character? I don't know if it is but I don't see why it wouldn't be -- `stdin` is opened in text mode, not binary mode I think, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad It is a character as anything else, which you can enter by pressing `^V^D`. In this case, it is not specially treated by the terminal, and really given to the program as `'\x04'`.

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't think that MacOS, being a kind of Unix, has something like "text mode" on files.

Comment: @Mehrdad, if MacOS behaves as POSIX mandates CTRL-D is not forwarded when it is interpreted by the terminal handling code.

Comment: I declare c as int to allow containment of a value impossible for char type, i.e. EOF. The question was actually "Why Ctrl-D in the middle of a line does not make the stream end up immediately?".

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> terminates the current `read()` call.

If you already have typed something, this "something" will be read back, and the return value of `read()` is the length of this "something".

Only if you are at the start of a line, `read()` will return 0, what is used as an indicator to EOF.